# Tektronix P6015 Replacement Potentiometer Considerations

Tags: high-voltage, potentiometer, probe, calibration, tektronix

I’ve acquired (saved from the landfill) an old Tektronix high voltage probe, model P6015. The probe body and cable are in decent condition, but I discovered two damaged potentiometers in the compensation box (R3, R5), one of which had been previously replaced with the wrong value.

[image: Compensation]

I managed to locate a copy of the original manual, and it indicates the following ratings for each:

[image: BOM]

I’m looking at sourcing comparable replacements, and there are plenty of options that can be made to fit mechanically into the previous location. I’d like to know if there are any considerations I should make based on the original circuit / age of the device, or if a standard 20% or lower tolerance potentiometer will be adequate?

I appreciate any suggestions from the community.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Tolerance doesn't mean much because it's an adjustable device.  You can dial-in whatever setting you need (Tolerance on a pot is a measure of end-to-end variability, for you here that's a "don't care").   There's a Power consideration (i.e. you don't want this getting hot) but in your case the power is negligible.  If your replacement is roughly the same physical size, it should have roughly the same power capability.  So in other words, use whatever mechanically fits and you should be fine.

Comment: @KyleB thanks for responding. I'll grab some basic pots and get to it.